# How to extract OTP token from a mail service and save it to a fixture

Tags: jquery, iframe, cypress, one-time-password

I am trying to save OTP text into my **Data.json** file and here it is a code.

```js
it.only('Otp Test', function () {
  cy.visit("https://www.mailinator.com/", { timeout: 30000 })
  cy.get("#addOverlay").type("jd")
  cy.get("#go-to-public").click()
  cy.wait(2000)
  cy.xpath("(//table/tbody/tr[1])[2]").click()
  cy.get('#html_msg_body').then(function ($ele) {
    var ifele = $ele.contents().find('body > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(3) > td > h2');
    cy.wrap(ifele).then(function (ele) {
      const OTP = ele.text();
      cy.readFile("cypress/fixtures/Data.json").then((profile) => {
        profile.OTP = OTP
        cy.writeFile("cypress/fixtures/Data.json", profile);
      })
    })
  })
})
```

Sometimes I'm getting this error

> Timed out retrying after 10000ms: Expected to find element: undefined, but never found it

in the **cy.wrap(ifele).then(function(ele) {**

I don't know what happens. anyone knows please help me.

Comment: On which line you are getting this error ?

Comment: Getting error in this line **cy.wrap(ifele).then(function (ele) {**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, the mail inbox changes so search for your OTP mail by text.

After clicking the email row, you need to wait for the iframe to load. The standard way is using `.its('0.contentDocument.body').should('not.be.empty')`.

```js
it.only('Otp Test', function () {
  cy.visit("https://www.mailinator.com/", { timeout: 30000 })
  cy.get("#addOverlay").type("jd")
  cy.get("#go-to-public").click()
  cy.wait(2000)
  cy.contains('table tbody tr', 'OTP').click()  // find the right email

  cy.get('#html_msg_body')  // iframe
    .its('0.contentDocument.body').should('not.be.empty')  // wait for loading
    .wait(0)    // some javascript needs to run in the iframe 
    .find('table > tbody > tr:nth-child(3) > td > h2')    
    .then($h2 => {    
      const OTP = $h2.text()
      cy.readFile("cypress/fixtures/Data.json").then((profile) => {
        profile.OTP = OTP
        cy.writeFile("cypress/fixtures/Data.json", profile);
      })
    })
})
```

---

**Footnote**

"Sometimes getting this error..." is because the iframe can take time to load it's source (like a browser within the browser).

Using `.should('not.be.empty')` repeats the read until it has some content.

Comment: It will getting the error `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'call')`

Comment: It's still working on my end.

Comment: Check the link for what it the error return cypress [https://ibb.co/YbqCbvj]

Comment: https://ibb.co/YbqCbvj

Comment: email is also there it have running script on your machine Please create email with "pari1" instead of "jd"

Comment: It is not working in my computer. Any other help you can do for me?

Comment: Now I'm getting the error - I removed a debugging line. Let me investigate

Comment: You can also use `.wait(0)` before the `.find()`. I think there is some javascript working in the iframe that needs to run before you can query the message body.  `.wait(0)` gives up the javascript thread to allow the message body to process (best guess).

Comment: Please Edit your answer so other people can learn. It will work well from my side.
`.wait(2000)
      .find("table:nth-child(1) tbody:nth-child(1) tr.MuiTypography-root.MuiTypography-body1:nth-child(3) td:nth-child(1) > h2:nth-child(1)")`
And Please upvote my question.

Comment: Already did upvote. Are you saying you need 2000ms wait? And wait(0) did not work?

Comment: Also, your long find selector is not required. The original is working perfectly well.